# .net 6 web API project still requires older hosting bundle to run

Tags: .net, iis, .net-6.0

I had Web API project which was hosted on IIS on windows server 2012.
I migrated the project to .net 6.
The application runs successfully. However when I remove older version of windows hosting bundle (2.1) the application stops functioning.
It's not just with my applicaiton. To test I created a dummy fresh web api in .net 6, and it also stopped functioning on removal of older .net bundle.

Comment: You need to repair the .NET 6 hosting bundle to restore the state. The old bundle uninstallers are not aware of the new bits (the new bits didn't even exist) so they can break the environment.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to reinstall .net6 after restarting the server.